# Incorrect Context error when calling bpy.ops.view3d.object_as_camera()

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I am using blender command line to render image . But before that I need to select active object as camera, which I am doing by calling `bpy.ops.view3d.object_as_camera()` .

However I am getting the wicked error 
`Operator bpy.ops.view3d.object_as_camera.poll() failed, context is incorrect`

Now when I do the following in Python Console in blender , the active camera is selected

```
bpy.data.objects['Camera001-5'].select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Camera001-5']
bpy.data.scenes[0].camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera001-5']
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        bpy.ops.view3d.object_as_camera(override)
        break
```

But when I run the script using blender command line, it gives error again.
What to do?

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out -

I had to add `area.spaces.active.region_3d.view_perspective = 'CAMERA'`
this in the loop.

Got my answer on http://blenderartists.org/. Just sharing for the community.

Comment: This saved me so much pain and frustration today.